# Html.Beginform open new tab in background

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, razor

I need to open a new tab in the background when the form is posted to the controller, because I have a progress bar on the page where the form was submitted.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("TestResults", "TestFunctions", null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", target = "_blank"}))
{
    <input class="btn btn-default" type="file" name="files" id="files" webkitdirectory directory multiple />
    <input class="btn btn-default progressButton" type="submit" name="submit" value="Test berichten" />
}
```

I have tried:

```
onclick="window.open('#','_blank');window.open(this.href,'_self');"
```

The solution has to work on IE9.

Thanks

Comment: Your example using `BeginForm` to set the `target` attribute should work. Have you checked what the HTML being output actually is?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan It does work, however when the button is pressed the new tab is focused, I want it to open in the background (popunder). I want to achieve this because the page takes a while to load when the input is a large amount of files to be processed

Comment: I see. You can't control where a new tab is opened as that's down to the user's browser preferences which is out of the scope of JS. It sounds like you would be much better to solve your problem by using an AJAX request.